# How to select elements by attribute's value when values contains dollar sign?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPH$ucFuncionEdit1$ckEsMenu" />
```

How can I select all elements with the same name using jQuery, the following fails:

```
jQuery('[name=ctl00$ContentPH$ucFuncionEdit1$ckEsMenu]');
```

The previous line of code raise the following error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   [name=ctl00$$ContentPH$$ucFuncionEdit1$$ckEsMenu]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You quote the value:

```
jQuery ('[name="ctl00$ContentPH$ucFuncionEdit1$ckEsMenu"]');
```

When dealing with attribute selectors, it's best to always quote the value (although if the value is a single word containing **only** the letters A-Z [case insensitive] and the digits 0-9 [but not starting with a digit], you can get away without).

Comment: For simple questions, simple answers :)

Comment: @Jack - I wasn't being passive-aggressive or snarky, I was using the [Socratic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method) to stimulate critical thinking. I'm sorry that didn't work. I strongly recommend not assuming the worst and going off at people. The answer is `jQuery('[id="ctl00$ContentPH$ucFuncionEdit1$ckEsMenu"]')`. `id` and `name` are both attributes, so you can use attribute selectors with both.  Good day.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the `$` sign with with two backslashes (`\\`):

`jQuery('[name=ctl00\\$ContentPH\\$ucFuncionEdit1\\$ckEsMenu]');`

Comment: \\$ is unescaped as \$, since \ escapes the character following it

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about clientid so you can do it in 2 ways:
1. when your js code in the same page where your html:

```
jQuery('#<%=ckEsMenu.ClientID%>').click();
```

2. when your js code is in separeted file:

```
jQuery("input[id$=ckEsMenu]").click();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use JS in same page, it is a bad practice, instead I use it at the bottom of my master page via `<asp:content />`. And the selector `jQuery("input[id$=ckEsMenu]")` it is not bullet-proof, would results in problem if you have two IDs ending with "ckEsMenu".

Comment: you use two elements with the same ID? why should you? that's not the best practice.

Comment: I meant two IDs _ending with_ "ckEsMenu", not two _same_ ids.

Comment: That does not matter what is ending of the ID. you should wright [id$=yourFullID].