# How to get a div having $ as first character

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose i have a div with ID '$abc'. How do i select it using jQuery?
Below is the sample code snippet.

```js
function abc(){
 $('#$abc').text('abc')
}
abc();
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div id="$abc"></div>
```

When i try running this i get an error in console like this-

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #$abc
at Function.ga.error (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
at ga.tokenize (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
at ga.select (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
at Function.ga [as find] (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.find (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
at r (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
at abc (fiddle.jshell.net/:46)
at window.onload (fiddle.jshell.net/:48)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select elements by attribute's value when values contains dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363066/how-to-select-elements-by-attributes-value-when-values-contains-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```js
function abc(){
 $('div[id="$abc"]').text('abc');
}
abc();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div id="$abc"></div>
```

Note:- this is called `[attribute|=value]` selectors

***Reference:-***  [All possible seletors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thanks !!
This does it. I knew this way but i don't know i could forgot about it.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas  glad to help you. :):) .

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
$('[id="$abc"]').text('abc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `$`  by placing two backslashes in front of it, try the following code:

```
function abc(){
    $('#\\$abc').text('abc')
}
abc();
```

Refer to [this doc](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) for more info.